# Word to describe a product that has a defect but was approved by a manager?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a quality control form I'm working on, there are 4 types of results for a product test:

- All quality requirements are attended (Approved);
- There is a minor defect in the product (Approved with remarks);
- There is a major defect in the product (Reproved);
- There is a major defect in the product, it would be considered as reproved, but a manager/coordinator can release it to market as is. This situation happens when a product has a defect but it will be sold with some discount or something like that.

The form is like this:

```
Test result:
( ) Approved
( ) Approved with remarks
( ) Reproved
( ) "word"
```

All translations point to "released", but this word sounds like a product that has no defects.

Considering that a person needs to "check" one of these 4 options in a form, what would be the correct word to use on the 4th result option?

Comment: I would call it "Max".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such goods are sometimes labelled as **second quality** or **seconds** which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/second) gives as

> **2.5** (**seconds**) Goods of an inferior quality.
>
> Synonyms: imperfect goods, faulty goods, defective goods, flawed goods, inferior goods, rejects, export rejects, discards.

---

The question does not ask about the other three terms, but I would reverse the sequence of the last two so they are in order of acceptability, and describe them thus

```
Test result:
( ) Approved
( ) Imperfect (state reason)
( ) Seconds (state reason)
( ) Reject
```

Comment: All these are good. You sometimes see other variations such as "second class", "B class", etc, on goods as well.

Answer (score 1):

A word that would probably distinguish that 4th option could be

> Admitted [to market with bugs]

Answer (score 1):

All quality requirements are attended (Approved);

I do not think 'attended' is the correct word here.  I think you are trying to use it in the context of: "All quality requirements [*have been*] attended [*to*]."  That is, all requirements are met or have been sorted out - the product is "First class" or top quality.  I think it would be better to phrase this as: "All quality requirements have been met."

There is a minor defect in the product (Approved with remarks);
There is a major defect in the product (Reproved);

Again, 'reproved' is not correct here.  **Reproved** means to reprimand (someone), or tell someone off for doing something wrong, for example: "*He was reproved for shouting in the library.*"

I would suggest: "Not fit for purpose" or simply "Defective" is more appropriate.

As far a a product 'Released to Service' with a known defect is concerned, the software industry tend to use 'Beta' to indicate an early release [probably] containing some defects, which may, or may not be known.

However, if a product, like a coat or a sofa is sold with known defects, this is usually either: "Sold as seen" - so that the purchaser is made aware that its not perfect - and cannot then sue for damages if it does not work properly, or the item is described as a "Second", that is, of a lesser quality (Second Class - as in a railway ticket) than the "First Quality" or "Premium" quality item.

Comment: Very good to know that the other words were wrong before I finish the form. I'm gonna accept Weather Vane answer because it was posted first with "second" as the correct word, but your answer helped me a lot too! Thank you very much! +1

Comment: No problem...  Glad we were able to help.